# How to create two groups of all combinations of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, combinations

I have a dataframe like an example here:

```
Site <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
Compound_1 <- c(0.5, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0, 0.25)
Compound_2 <- c(0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 0.25, 0)
df <- data.frame(Site, Compound_1, Compound_2)

print (df)
```

I want to create separate dataframes of all combinations that could be made by splitting these rows into two groups. For example in combination 1, group x will include site 1 and group y sites 2-6. The next combination would have group x include site 2 and group y sites 1 and 3-6. Given I have six total "sites" in my dataframe, the code should produce 64 different combinations. I want the final format to be 2 dataframes per combination that also includes all the information on Compound_1 and Compound_2, not just the site numbers listed out. I'm guessing a for loop is the best way to do this but I am lost on even how to start.

Comment: I imagine storing all the row indexes for each split and then looping over these to do your analysis would be far more efficient than needing to store all the copies of each `data.frame`.

Comment: what output you expect ?

Comment: How do you get `64` combinations? This is like a leave one out problem. You should have 6 combinations since there are 6 groups. Why 64?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

# enumerate all the possible combinations of sites and groups
grps <- c("x","y")
tibble(V1 = grps, V2 = grps, V3 = grps,
           V4 = grps, V5 = grps, V6 = grps) %>%
  complete(V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6) %>%
  mutate(combo_num = row_number(), .before = 1) %>%

  # reshape to long
  pivot_longer(-combo_num, names_to = "Site", ,
               names_transform = parse_number,
               values_to = "Group") %>%

  # join with original data
  left_join(df) -> output
```

This produces a long table with all the combinations, with each Site having its original values.

```
Joining, by = "Site"
# A tibble: 384 × 5
   combo_num  Site Group Compound_1 Compound_2
       <int> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1         1     1 x           0.5        0.25
 2         1     2 x           0.25       0.5 
 3         1     3 x           0.5        0.5 
 4         1     4 x           0.75       0.75
 5         1     5 x           0          0.25
 6         1     6 x           0.25       0   
 7         2     1 x           0.5        0.25
 8         2     2 x           0.25       0.5 
 9         2     3 x           0.5        0.5 
10         2     4 x           0.75       0.75
# … with 374 more rows
```

From there, we could summarize as needed. For instance, to get all the combinations of `x` sites,

```
x_combos <- output %>%
  filter(Group == "x")
```

Or we might look at what weights are produced in group X by each combination:

```
output %>%
  filter(Group == "x") %>%
  group_by(combo_num) %>%
  summarize(across(Compound_1:Compound_2, sum))

# A tibble: 63 × 3
   combo_num Compound_1 Compound_2
       <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>
 1         1       2.25       2.25
 2         2       2          2.25
 3         3       2.25       2   
 4         4       2          2   
 5         5       1.5        1.5 
 6         6       1.25       1.5 
 7         7       1.5        1.25
 8         8       1.25       1.25
 9         9       1.75       1.75
10        10       1.5        1.75
# … with 53 more rows
```